# Restarting shell script with &disown using Monit

Tags: linux, monitoring, process, monit, pid

I have a shell script that runs a C++ backend mail system (PluginHandler).
I need to monitor this process in Monit and restart it if it fails.

The script:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/:/CONFIDENTAL/CONFIDENTAL/Common/
cd PluginHandler/
./PluginHandler
```

This script does not have a PID file and we run this script by executing

```
./rundaemon.sh &disown
```

./pluginhandler starts the process and starts logging into /etc/output/output.log
I stop the process by identifying the process ID with [ps -f | grep PluginHandler] and then killing the process.

I can check the process in Monit just fine, but I think Monit is starting the process if it is not running but it can't do &disown so the process ends as soon as it starts.

This is the code in the monitrc file for checking this process:

```
check process Backend
matching "PluginHandler"
if not exist
then alert
start "PATH/TO/SCRIPT/rundaemon.sh &disown"
alert example@gmail.com only on {timeout} with mail-format {subject: "[BLAH"}
```

I tried to stop the script from terminating by modifying the script like the following but this does not work either.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/:/home/CONFIDENTAL/production/CONFIDENTAL/Common/
cd PluginHandler/
(nohup ./PluginHandler &)
return
```

Any help to write a proper Monit rules to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use disown...

I don't know the full contents of the script, but you should really try to use a PID file if possible. But you can use Monit to start and stop the process regardless.

```
check process Backend
        matching "PluginHandler"
        start program = "/path/to/rundaemon.sh" as uid user
        stop program = "/usr/bin/pkill -f PluginHandler"
```

This alone will make sure the process is working. You'll probably want something more specific in the "matching" string. Test with `monit procmatch <string>` to see what Monit will detect. It will only monitor the first occurrence of the matched process.

You can start the process with `monit start Backend` and stop it with `monit stop Backend`, provided there's a graceful method to stop the script.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply.  I tried your suggestion but this does not work.  The monit log states "'Backend' failed to start".  It attempts to restart the Backend but keeps failing.